# How frequent can we do SQL transaction log backups?

Tags: backup, logging, sql

I'm installing a highly critical system. If the system fails, the users wants data up to the last minute.

To achieve this, I was thinking of running Transaction Log Backups + FTP every minute. Has anybody done this before? Is this the best way to achieve the 1-minute data loss tolerance?

Appreciate any advice,

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you can do frequent tx log, but it still looses data.

Best approach is:

- 3 database servers, one small free edition as witness, using safe mirroring.

2 copies of the database, kept in sync.

Then use DPM (Data Protection Manager) to make near real time backups of that.

Particularly target an ugprade to SQ LServer 2012 asap and mirror the database files on both servers (total: 4 copies of the database), preferably on separate casings / raid controllers.

Yes, that gets expensive -but then "highly critical" means "pay what it takes".

And you do not need FTP - SQL Server Log File Shipping can ship out the logs itself via file share.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The thing is this is not for mirroring. It's just for SQL Backup Only. + It is expensive. What's wrong with using regular log backup?

Comment: THat you will loose data. Point. In my world "Highly Critical" means "I am not allowed to loose data". Like financial trading applications. It means immediately "backup sytem real time mirrored in another data center". Your definition of highly critical maybe 99.99%, but this is not highly critical for the world. Also note that your system may be down for days anyway without available backup system (takes time to get a datbase server delivered and installed). The third machine can be a small virtual one.

Answer (score 0):

At that frequency, you'd probably be better off using [database mirroring](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189852.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

For deploying High Availability solutions, I always recommend the use of HP Storage mirroring software. 
http://h18006.www1.hp.com/products/storage/software/sm/